# How to get all the 'href' links with the help of using Following siblings in selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C://Users//psingh//AppData//Local//Programs//Python//Python38-32//chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPI_Files.html")
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[./td[./b[text()='Weekly Incremental NPI Files']]]/following-sibling::tr//a")
ele = element.get_attribute("href")
print(ele)
driver.quit()
```

I want to get all 4 'href' links below 'Weekly Incremental NPI Files' Heading. with above code I am only able to get top 1st link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` elements with an **s** to get all in element and than loop over the result:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPI_Files.html")
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[./td[./b[text()='Weekly Incremental NPI Files']]]/following-sibling::tr//a")
ele = [ele.get_attribute("href") for ele in element]
print(ele)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: you get this error,  TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Comment: Do you used my example?  Output is: `['https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_120720_121320_Weekly.zip', 'https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_121420_122020_Weekly.zip', 'https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_122120_122720_Weekly.zip', 'https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_122820_010321_Weekly.zip', '']` sure that you changed `driver.find_element_by_xpath` to `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` with an s?

Comment: Yes I got it, I haven't changed the code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the tag "a" easily with these xpath:

```
xpath = "\\a[contains(@href,'NPPES Data')]"
```

It will get all "a" tags that have href adapt the condition.